# Lubuntu 20.04 OEM install not working

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, oem

I need to install Lubuntu 20.04 on an old machine that I intend to give away to someone who needs it, maybe a charity. For this purpose, I want to make use of the OEM install.

When booting Ubuntu 20.04 from a Live USB, it presents several options on the boot page, including "OEM install (for manufacturers)". This allows me to install Ubuntu, tailor it (e.g. install updates), and then "Prepare for shipping to end user".

However, it's different for Lubuntu. It presents the same options as Ubuntu on the boot page (see the screenshot), but when I select "OEM install (for manufacturers)", it simply boots to a normal Lubuntu as if I'd selected the first option, "Start Lubuntu".

How do I get the OEM installation to work on Lubuntu, please?

[image: Boot options from Live USB]

Comment: I'm not aware of there being one, the OEM option exists in the menu yes, but it's not used by Lubuntu on any release post 18.10.  You could file a bug, and we'll look to see if we can remove it (yeah, it is misleading; that or implement/complete T(ask)16; https://phab.lubuntu.me/T16).

Comment: @guiverc — Thank you for your reply. That's sad! Never mind, I'll work a way around it. That link that you gave: is that a bug report, or do you suggest that I file a new one? If I should file a new one, do you know the best place to do it?

Comment: Bugs would be filed on launchpad (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), the link I gave was the Lubuntu task (number 16) on making the OEM functionality work. The desire to get it working is there, but a lack of resources is the problem (a bug report may prompt some effort, though I suspect it'll cause the option to disappear from the listed options; I just did a *groovy* QA-install & didn't see the OEM option listed so maybe it's gone already; I don't have time to explore)

Comment: @guiverc — Thanks. I've submitted [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1901056).

Comment: Just an FYI:  Boot the same thumb drive on an older BIOS (non-uEFI) system and the OEM option won't appear (you'll more likely get a Start, Start (safe graphics), Test memory, Boot hdd).  The number of options offered varies on box/device ISO is booted on (not always five), but that doesn't matter; your point was clear.

Comment: The OEM install option is working on Ubuntu 20.04. Do you need to install Lubuntu? Ubuntu works fine for me on some pretty old computers and I sure prefer the interface.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron this is equivalent to a bug report about this not working on **Lubuntu ISOs**.  We know that Ubuntu ISOs work with OEM install, but they use ubiquity/subiquity, while Lubuntu uses Calamares as its installer.

Comment: @Thomas Ward: Of course I tested OEM install with Lubuntu 20.04 ISO, it does not work. Yes I did test this with Ubuntu 20.04.1 ISO before posting, it did work. Paddy wants to get rid of an old computer. It could be months before a Bug Report shows results and it sounds like those results will just be removing OEM from the boot menu. I don't think a Bug  Report will help him. Therefore installing Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu sounds like a valid option. I did not test OEM with Xubuntu or other light 'buntus.

Comment: @guiverc — I just tried, and you're correct! How odd.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron — There is a big difference between Ubuntu and Lubuntu; about 1Gb RAM. On my old computer, that makes an enormous difference in the use of swap, in speed, and in the number of times it crashes. As far as I can tell, Lubuntu is the lightest of all the assorted official Ubuntu flavours.

Comment: FYI: as for booting options varying on devices..  that no longer applies with 20.10 & later, with the multiple booting systems no longer required (which applied all prior releases); https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-to-use-grub2-for-booting-installer-media-in-any-modes-on-all-architectures/16871

Comment: mkusb has been using GRUB2 to boot in BIOS mode for a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Chris Guiver (guiverc here on Ask Ubuntu, and a member of the Lubuntu team per their [Launchpad Profile](https://launchpad.net/%7Eguiverc)) has indicated in the comments to this question that since 18.10, the Lubuntu OEM Install option on the Lubuntu ISO is not in use and has not been used/functional since 18.10.

As such, it simply does not work for Lubuntu 20.04.  The feature request tracking task for this is at these locations:

- Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1901056
- Lubuntu Phabricator (Lubuntu bug/task tracker): https://phab.lubuntu.me/T16

  - There's some technical details in here about getting this done, mostly that it takes time and testing and none on the Lubuntu Team actually had any interest in testing/developing this out; this task has not moved much since pre-20.04 so it may end up being decided that it's Won't Fix if they ultimately choose that they don't have time to implement this feature.

Also per Chris (in the comments as well), 20.10 Groovy ISOs do not contain an OEM Install option, **so it's possible that it was removed officially from the Lubuntu ISO options and as such is unlikely to be implemented**.

If, however, the Lubuntu Team does choose to implement the OEM Install option, chances are that it might not land in older releases of the Lubuntu ISO for some time.