# Ubuntu Studio 21.04 OEM installer not working

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-studio, oem

I'm trying to install Studio 21.04 in OEM mode to donate a few iMacs that have met their planned obsolescence date. Can anyone confirm if Studio has gone the way of [Lubuntu as in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285953/lubuntu-20-04-oem-install-not-working)?
I am having the same issue, I select the OEM install, but do not get the OEM installer.
If that's the case I guess my route will be install Kubuntu in OEM mode and run the Ubuntu Studio Installer over that.

Comment: Kubuntu uses the `ubiquity` installer (with a KDE-Qt skin over it) so it offers OEM.  With `calamares` it's still a work in progress, and yes is the installer of recent release(s) of Ubuntu Studio.  As `ubiquity` is being replaced it's hoped for 21.10 or *impish* (see the *canary* build), I believe the Ubuntu Studio team hope to revert back to `ubiquity` but only time will tell (`ubiquity` is GTK+ and is hardcoded for KDE/Qt which is why Lubuntu/Ubuntu Studio also using Qt5 cannot use it;  Ubuntu Studio could of course use it whilst they used Xfce/GTK3 but now use KDE/Qt5 too)

Comment: if interested - https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/871  but note whilst I'm not part of the Ubuntu Studio team so cannot speak with any authority, I've seen discussions (IRC) about them using the new installer once it's available (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659) as it won't have the *limitations* that existed within `ubiquity` for Qt5 based desktops not named Kubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That makes sense. So I'll use the Kubuntu/Studio installer method, at least for the boxes that are going into the outreach program. I'll be the admin for the ones staying at the computer lab so I guess I'll just go Studio with them.

Comment: Using 20.04 LTS version would be better for donation. This will make life of new user easier.

Comment: There is a *load* of advantages to LTS for donated/recycled hardware... I've volunteered in a *recycler* and we only used LTS releases, though as Ubuntu Studio 20.04 was the last release using XFCE, warning was given it would require re-install past that release.  (https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-lts-released/)

Comment: Great point on the LTS call. I think for that I'll still go the Kubuntu 20.04 and run the studio installer so the end-user doesn't run into any issues. I suppose I could just run an OEM install and be done with it as they are just donations to those who don't have reliable computer access, but the community we support is active in the arts so I wanted to give anyone who might want to use the programs a head start if they're not familiar with opensource software.

Answer (score 0):

Per @guiverc Lubuntu and Ubuntu Studio currently using Calamares installer, OEM installations aren't presently possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly opinion.. but explains why

Kubuntu uses the `ubiquity` installer (*with a KDE-Qt skin over it*) so it offers OEM.

With `calamares` it's still a [work in progress](https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/871), and yes that is the installer of recent release(s) of Ubuntu Studio.

As `ubiquity` is being replaced [with a new installer](https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-desktop-installer) it's hoped for 21.10 or *impish* (see the daily *canary* build if you want to have a look), I believe the Ubuntu Studio team may use the *new* standard Ubuntu Desktop installer (`ubiquity` replacement)  but only time will tell (*they'll make up their own mind when a decision needs to be made*).

`ubiquity` is GTK+ and is hard-coded for KDE/Qt which is why Lubuntu/Ubuntu Studio also using Qt5 cannot use it  (*Ubuntu Studio could of course use `ubiquity` whilst they used Xfce/GTK3, but now use KDE/Qt5 too*). The new [Ubuntu Desktop installer](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659) may mean Ubuntu Studio can use that in the future instead of `calamares` they currently use as it won't have the *limitations* that existed within `ubiquity` for Qt5 based desktops not named Kubuntu.