# Ubuntu Studio 21.10: creation of OEM setup doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, bug-reporting, oem

Hello and a happy new year

Since years I tried to create in Virtual Box or other machines an OEM setup for "shipping" (as download file), but the dialogue for *OEM setup* doesn't load but it boot directly to the desktop surface.

Is there a solution that the *OEM setup* can work or is it really a bug?

Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu MATE no problems to create OEM setups

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio has used the `calamares` installer for the recent KDE based releases which doesn't have OEM setup. Ubuntu Studio are *hoping* to return to offering OEM with 22.04, but it's not a bug, but a known & documented issue as a side effect of using `calamares`.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351026/ubuntu-studio-21-04-oem-installer-not-working  and https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/871

Comment: OK, then I hope too that the OEM will return to make OEM 

Comment: FYI:  It's beginning to look like it may not be offered for 22.04 either (*Ubuntu Studio would have switched to the newer desktop installer currently in canary builds for OEM to return*) but it's still early and there is a possibility.

Comment: The new Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with start into OEM runs in live mode again. OEM mode doesn't work again :-(

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 is still using `calamares` thus OEM isn't supported...  It maybe offered when the still *canary* installer is deemed *stable* for use, or it's added to `calamares`.  ***Its not that it (OEM) doesn't work; it's that it's not currently a supported install option***. *Lubuntu's task can be found [here](https://phab.lubuntu.me/T16), but if Ubuntu Studio have one I'm unaware of it, but both Ubuntu Studio & Lubuntu both manage `calamares` that we both use so we're aware of what each other does even if I can't provide a Ubuntu-Studio link*